# Extra space at top of SVG

Tags: wordpress, svg, path, pixel

I created an SVG for a site. Everything works fine, but for some reason both of the semi circle SVG's have a weird extra couple pixels height in the middle. It almost looked like part of a jagged edge, but I changed the SVG's shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" . This did fix jagged edges around the circle but that small couple pixels are extra in the center. First thought was maybe the svg was generated with this but when viewed anywhere outside of the website I am using it on these extra pixels aren't there. Code for an SVG:

```
<svg id="a1c72157-41bb-43e5-9ecb-ca4cc4c406e1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920.1141 217.1052" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
  <path d="M1921,131c0,27.1667-.1,54.3341.1133,81.4991.03,3.856-.7636,4.6068-4.6133,4.6061Q959,216.9407,1,217V120l2.4731-1.5564,10.3736-3.0393,2.7067-.7908,4.28-1.2731,2.1257-.5438,1.8665-.5419,2.1123-.5547,4.9-1.3945,2.6494-.8481,1.4889-.3091,5.5751-1.604L64.83,101.2264l2.122-.4617,1.8787-.5481,2.1281-.4188L72.83,99.252l2.1223-.4829,1.8746-.5266,2.1108-.5394,1.8967-.4521,2.6556-.7768,1.4791-.2725,2.5079-.7708,1.5017-.2979,2.5077-.6843,1.49-.2912,1.9714-.4087,1.8842-.54,2.1213-.4361,1.8758-.54,2.1273-.4474,1.8739-.4788,2.1258-.5228,1.8753-.4771,2.1244-.5225,1.8737-.5236,2.1313-.4511,1.876-.4629,3.0942-.659,1.8964-.5354,2.1149-.4281,1.89-.4443,2.1228-.4955,2.878-.6155,2.65-.7016,1.4861-.2747,2.5241-.7371L165.8317,77.19l2.1222-.4145,1.8861-.4815,3.69-.7365,2.46-.4915,1.9514-.3447,1.8934-.5193,3.0922-.528,1.9059-.4743,2.1267-.4,2.87-.6079,2.1128-.4739,2.8945-.531,2.6922-.6279,2.4486-.4166,2.5678-.5711,2.4436-.4957,1.9537-.3578,1.8927-.4369,3.1106-.5344,1.89-.4337,3.1109-.5627,1.894-.3764,3.1121-.5974,2.8751-.5572,2.126-.4452,1.89-.3889,3.1209-.5484,2.8677-.6347,3.0977-.5143,1.9076-.4333,3.7149-.6035,2.423-.4849,1.9871-.35,8.8757-1.573,2.7221-.6L262.99,58.06l2.5445-.51,2.4579-.501,1.9756-.2091,8.8629-1.6852,2.1363-.322,2.8743-.45,3.1054-.6309,2.8944-.3938,3.1071-.5948,3.891-.6242,2.7084-.5141,3.4381-.5389,2.5871-.42,3.4162-.5987,3.5249-.5528,3.4883-.53,1.9462-.2342,4.0539-.7667,1.9524-.2079,8.8843-1.4447,3.1185-.5313,3.8756-.5682,3.1072-.51,2.8964-.4658,4.0957-.5591,2.9016-.48,3.1217-.4223,2.8829-.4821,4.1091-.5466,2.8908-.4556,4.1007-.5792,4.033-.5608,3.57-.5841,3.43-.4167,3.5809-.5522,2.4158-.4172,3.9762-.4411,4.0415-.6766,2.9707-.2829,3.877-.6174,2.1457-.28,5.8517-.741,2.1355-.3228,4.8683-.5834,3.13-.4124,5.0085-.682,3.948-.4925,1.9127-.45,5.1143-.4447,2.885-.5281,4.1325-.4008,4.867-.6614,4.1189-.3992,3.8864-.4745,4.1114-.532,6.0285-.6509,3.5676-.5209,5.4329-.4816,3.5628-.5363,5.4441-.5024,2.9554-.3435,6.0527-.7067,2.962-.24,7.0461-.8134,1.9638-.15,6.0293-.806,3.9568-.2447,5.0195-.5974,2.9985-.3226,6.8648-.6253,4.1166-.455,5.8863-.5381,5.105-.4927,5.0253-.553,5.9661-.4784,3.9041-.4954,7.0973-.499,4.9014-.54,5.1068-.43,7.0282-.5822,4.9747-.407,8.0328-.6418,3.9763-.32,8.0208-.6649,5.9607-.4065,5.0435-.6193,6.9731-.3176,5.8814-.6318,3.1422-.27,10.8592-.6839,4.1379-.3273,10.8631-.6261,5.1311-.3975L677.9678,9.2l5.995-.3724,6.8781-.5822,11.1159-.4428,6.8833-.5678L721.9414,6.74l5.9028-.4173L740.9491,5.77l10.0146-.5448,13.9807-.4728,12.0248-.5668,10.9789-.42,20.0228-.591,11.985-.3766,27.0179-.6432,24.9442-.508,3.93-.0917,54.161-.5281L941,.9988l15,0,8.989.0342,45.155.5634,1.931.0408,33.9544.5044L1062.058,2.7l19.9728.4507,13.0285.545,15.9711.4533,11.0323.5338,12.9739.4988,11.0194.5315,12.0972.5868,8.8942.4466,9.1069.5616,7.903.3926,10.097.6166,6.8918.43,10.108.5776,5.89.43,10.1109.5545,4.893.4256,9.109.5273,5.8839.51,5.9857.3636,7.0265.5734,5.9839.483,8.0034.582,5.0044.4655,6.01.4737,5.9773.4511,5.0351.5,6.9578.4629,5.0426.5329,6.9586.4717,5.0363.55,5.9707.49,5.03.503,6.0971.54,4.8991.4724,6.0944.6581,4.8886.4157,5.1138.5707,4.8816.449,5.12.5387,3.8792.4713,5.1246.3945,3.8831.5653,3.9607.2769,6.0287.7739,2.9711.2259,4.4925.46,4.52.6022,4.48.3973,4.5316.6609,4.4563.3756,4.6744.6773,4.8925.5151,4.1118.5033,3.8894.4912,5.1093.5478,3.8709.5417,5.121.5677,3.8655.5024,4.1384.4652,1.8947.3741,5.1087.4463,2.8826.5914,2.9759.3644,5.0121.6908,3.1313.4155,4.8637.6021,1.9888.2739,6.0054.7657,2.1446.323,4.87.5951,2.1355.3769,2.8875.5334,5.1015.5942,1.9042.388,5.0955.5793,1.9107.3915,3.9617.54,2.447.3436,4.5646.7162,3.9906.5523,3.1259.5169,3.8714.4918,3.1228.5808,2.88.4023,3.1278.5357,1.8937.3768,4.109.4932,1.9044.4494,4.0894.5071,2.8916.5692,2.9753.4288,2.4629.3572,3.5356.6284,3.4231.5109,2.7111.4705,3.8875.6293,3.1175.5394,1.9038.3761,4.0931.6423,1.8975.3977,4.1011.614,1.8992.3789,4.0981.6611,1.8941.3637,4.1039.6534,2.8653.503,2.1464.4033,12.8843,2.4469,3.1121.43,2.8747.629,1.9763.3032,2.47.4269,3.5548.6983,2.4189.396,2.7045.5311,3.8673.6882,2.1345.4738,2.8834.4293,3.1007.7239,1.8916.3114,3.1142.6517,1.881.3819,3.129.52,1.87.48,2.1345.3549,2.8678.6289,1.9854.3516,2.4375.4511,2.5606.5258,2.4435.4432,2.5666.61,2.4447.3773,2.6879.7124,2.8756.5216,2.13.5083,1.8786.4592,3.1187.5085,1.8765.5082,1.9706.319,2.42.551,2.59.4923,2.4171.5258,2.72.5864,1.9014.418,2.1139.5315,2.868.562,2.1265.5442,6.8612,1.5131,2.1382.3841,1.8782.5317,1.9551.3069,6.45,1.5309,2.5846.6483,1.4939.2305,2.6337.7292,2.8693.6385,2.13.5216,1.88.4207,2.1274.4513,1.8864.4926,7.1018,1.61,1.876.4878,2.1336.4843,1.8683.4969,2.1326.522,1.87.4615,2.132.5045,1.8686.4976,2.13.4328,1.8707.5646,2.1263.467,1.8764.52,1.98.4144,1.4721.3225,2.53.6724,1.4895.3051,2.6448.8009,1.898.4222,2.1116.5957,1.879.4455,2.1222.5576,1.8649.5106,6.125,1.5045,1.8655.5457,2.1378.5019,4.3608,1.0958,2.6355.7448,1.8873.5357,2.1174.5916,11.42,3.0492,2.4236.7063,1.464.4724,2.6877.683,1.8689.6094,5.137,1.4411,1.8726.4961,2.117.6571,4.8775,1.3605,8.1314,2.3888,1.8771.5833,5.1234,1.4824,4.3132,1.2614,5.69,1.672,1.8585.6707,8.1394,2.4273,13.37,4.1343,5.6251,1.9Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M875.8478,1.5551Q875.9239.7775,876,0h54l.0088,1.027Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1010,0q.072.7983.1439,1.5967l-45.155-.5634L965,0Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M956,.9991l-15,0Q941,.4995,941,0h15Q956,.5,956,.9991Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M941,0q0,.4994,0,.9988l-10.9914.0282L930,0Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M956,.9991Q956,.5,956,0h9l-.0111,1.0333Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1,118l2.4729.4433Q2.2366,119.222,1,120Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1012.0749,1.6375l33.9544.5044Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M846.9738,2.1548l24.9442-.508Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1062.058,2.7l19.9728.4506Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1095.0593,3.6959l15.9711.4532Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M750.9637,5.2249l13.9807-.4728Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1122.0627,4.683l12.9739.4988Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M727.8442,6.3222,740.9491,5.77Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M708.84,7.2351,721.9414,6.74Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M807.9709,3.1746l11.985-.3766Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1146.056,5.7133l12.0972.5869Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M776.9692,4.1853l10.9789-.42Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M690.8409,8.2457l11.1159-.4428Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1184.0573,7.7009l10.097.6167Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1201.0461,8.7475l10.108.5777Q1206.1,9.0361,1201.0461,8.7475Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1217.0446,9.7548l10.1109.5546Q1222.1,10.0319,1217.0446,9.7548Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1167.0474,6.7467l9.1069.5617Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1232.0485,10.7349l9.109.5274Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1892.0289,121.8356l8.1394,2.4274Q1896.0987,123.0492,1892.0289,121.8356Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M559.8392,18.2209l7.0973-.499Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1308.0681,16.66l6.9586.4717Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1865.0356,113.7769l8.1314,2.3888Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1296.0677,15.6644l6.9578.4629Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M619.9817,13.1107l6.9731-.3176Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1761.06,86.6854l7.1018,1.6105Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1260.0536,12.7091l5.9839.483Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M608.9775,14.1365l5.9607-.4065Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1285.0553,14.7133l5.9773.4511Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1247.0414,11.7721l5.9857.3636Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M677.9678,9.2l5.995-.3724Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1320.063,17.6818l5.9707.49Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M549.969,19.1947l5.9661-.4784Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1331.0635,18.6749l6.0971.54Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1342.06,19.687l6.0944.6582Q1345.1068,20.0159,1342.06,19.687Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1810.0381,98.7818l6.125,1.5046Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1274.0409,13.7741l5.0044.4654Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M583.9729,16.17l4.9747-.407Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M571.8379,17.182l5.1068-.43Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M661.8386,10.2539l5.1311-.3975Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M539.8387,20.24l5.105-.4927Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1353.0427,20.7608l5.1138.5708Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1509.0662,39.67l5.0955.5793Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1363.0381,21.7805l5.12.5388Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1502.0605,38.6877l5.1015.5943Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1372.037,22.7905l5.1246.3945Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1458.054,32.7092l5.1087.4463Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M430.8355,32.2155l5.1143-.4447Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1443.0344,30.8l5.121.5678Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1434.0542,29.71l5.1093.548Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1913.5388,128.397l5.6251,1.9Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M35.9759,109.1483q2.7872-.8024,5.5747-1.6044Q38.7636,108.3466,35.9759,109.1483Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1851.0315,109.822q2.5684.7207,5.137,1.4412Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1875.0441,116.749l5.1234,1.4824Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1884.4807,119.4928l5.69,1.6721Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M455.84,29.3068l4.1114-.532Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1426.053,28.7158l4.1118.5034Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M447.8343,30.1805l4.1189-.3992Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1604.0519,54.7142l4.1039.6535Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M438.8348,31.2427l4.1325-.4008Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1598.06,53.6894l4.0981.6612Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1381.0447,23.75l3.9607.2769Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1452.0209,31.87l4.1384.4652Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M424.9748,33.1585l3.948-.4925Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1416.4861,27.5234l4.6744.6773Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1592.0594,52.6965l4.1011.6141Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1586.0688,51.6565l4.0931.6424Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M529.8358,21.2335l4.1166-.455Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M596.98,15.1213l3.9763-.32Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1407.4982,26.4869l4.5316.6609Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M646.8376,11.2073l4.1379-.3273Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1398.4977,25.4874l4.52.6022Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1555.071,46.64l4.0894.5071Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M386.97,38.1982l3.9762-.4411Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1549.0576,45.697l4.109.4933Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M345.8371,44.2546l4.0957-.5591Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M510.9962,23.0235l3.9568-.2447Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1522.4811,41.5242l4.5646.7162Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M358.839,42.3106l4.1091-.5466Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M365.8389,41.3084l4.1007-.5791Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1516.0724,40.6407l3.9617.54Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M519.9725,22.1814l2.9985-.3226Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M373.9726,40.1684q1.7849-.2925,3.57-.5846Q375.758,39.8766,373.9726,40.1684Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M352.8344,43.215l3.1217-.4223Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1531.0363,42.7927l3.1259.517Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M380.9728,39.1676q1.79-.2767,3.58-.5527Q382.7634,38.8918,380.9728,39.1676Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1538.0336,43.8014l3.1228.5809Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M339.8335,45.23l3.1072-.51Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1544.0361,44.7845l3.1278.5358Q1545.6,45.0522,1544.0361,44.7845Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M332.8394,46.33l3.1185-.5313Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M632.8362,12.1613l3.1422-.27Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M474.98,27.1214q1.7811-.2687,3.5624-.5368Q476.7616,26.8536,474.98,27.1214Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M394.9872,37.0805l2.9707-.2829Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1562.052,47.7159l2.9753.4288Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1474.0333,34.8021q1.5655.2079,3.1313.4155Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1567.49,48.5019l3.5356.6284Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M308.9894,50.0659q1.7621-.2769,3.5246-.5533Q310.7519,49.79,308.9894,50.0659Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M116.8372,88.3465l3.0942-.6589Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M483.9869,26.0827l2.9554-.3435Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1581.0475,50.741l3.1175.54Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M465.98,28.1239q1.7835-.261,3.5672-.5215Q467.7635,27.8637,465.98,28.1239Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1466.0453,33.7469l2.9759.3644Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M289.8415,53.3571l3.1071-.5948Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M416.8361,34.2529l3.13-.4124Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M283.8417,54.3818l3.1054-.6309Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M492.995,25.0325l2.962-.24Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M169.84,76.2939q1.8448-.3687,3.69-.7369Q171.6853,75.9259,169.84,76.2939Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1391.0341,24.8011l2.9711.2259Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M179.8347,74.2019l3.0922-.528Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1698.0479,72.7391l3.1187.5085Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M208.835,68.2807l3.1106-.5344Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M213.8358,67.3126l3.1109-.5627Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1626.0518,58.7208l3.1121.43Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1664.0358,65.7955l3.129.52Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M218.8407,66.3735l3.1121-.5974Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1636.4849,60.51l3.5548.6983Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M239.838,62.2541q1.8572-.3024,3.7146-.6041Q241.6956,61.9527,239.838,62.2541Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1659.0406,64.7618l3.1142.6518Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M234.8327,63.2017l3.0977-.5143Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1654.0483,63.7266l3.1007.724Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M228.8441,64.3848l3.1209-.5483Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1649.03,62.8235l2.1345.4738Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M224.8279,65.219l2.126-.4453Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1642.4586,61.6042l2.7045.5311Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M245.9759,61.1657l1.9871-.35Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1632.0386,59.78l1.9763.3032Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M256.8387,59.2426q1.3608-.3006,2.7218-.6007Q258.2,58.9427,256.8387,59.2426Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1669.0352,66.795l2.1345.3549Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M262.99,58.06q1.2718-.2554,2.5442-.5105Q264.2627,57.8048,262.99,58.06Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1674.0375,67.7788l1.9854.3516Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M204.9886,69.0754l1.9537-.3578Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1678.46,68.5815l2.5606.5258Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M199.9772,70.1422q1.2835-.2859,2.5674-.5715Q201.2612,69.8569,199.9772,70.1422Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1683.4645,69.5505l2.5666.61Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M194.8364,71.1867q1.3458-.3144,2.6919-.6283Q196.1827,70.873,194.8364,71.1867Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1688.4758,70.5377l2.6879.7123Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M189.8291,72.1917l2.1128-.474Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1694.0393,71.7716l2.13.5084Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M184.8328,73.2l2.1267-.4Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M267.9926,57.0486l1.9756-.2091Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1611.0211,55.8706l2.1464.4033Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1703.0431,73.7558l1.9706.319Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M175.99,75.0659l1.9514-.3447Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1707.4335,74.6258l2.59.4923Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M278.8311,55.1543l2.1363-.322Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1712.4408,75.6439l2.72.5864Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M165.8317,77.19l2.1222-.4145Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1717.0627,76.6483l2.1139.5315Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1722.0446,77.7418l2.1265.5443Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1731.0323,79.7991l2.1382.3842Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1735.0487,80.7149l1.9551.3069Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1743.4537,82.5527l2.5846.6483Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M134.97,84.1925q1.2616-.3688,2.5238-.7374Q136.2324,83.8241,134.97,84.1925Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1747.5322,83.4315l2.6337.7293Q1748.8491,83.796,1747.5322,83.4315Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M130.8337,85.1688q1.325-.3513,2.65-.702Q132.1591,84.8181,130.8337,85.1688Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1753.0352,84.7992l2.13.5217Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M125.8329,86.28l2.1228-.4955Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1757.0458,85.7415l2.1274.4513Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M121.8278,87.1522l2.1149-.4281Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M296.84,52.1381q1.3539-.2576,2.7081-.5145Q298.1939,51.8813,296.84,52.1381Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1574.4489,49.6412l2.7111.4706Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M112.83,89.2606l2.1313-.4511Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1770.0374,88.7836l2.1336.4843Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M108.8318,90.3067l2.1244-.5225Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1774.0393,89.7649l2.1326.5219Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M104.8307,91.3066l2.1258-.5228Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1778.0422,90.7483l2.132.5046Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M100.83,92.2328l2.1273-.4474Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1782.0428,91.75l2.13.4329Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M96.8324,93.2086l2.1213-.4361Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1786.0437,92.7478l2.1263.467Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M92.9768,94.1574l1.9714-.4086Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1790.0464,93.7349l1.98.4145Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M88.9789,95.133q1.2536-.3424,2.5074-.6846Q90.2329,94.791,88.9789,95.133Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1793.4985,94.4719l2.53.6723Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M84.9693,96.2017q1.2536-.3857,2.5076-.7711Q86.2234,95.8164,84.9693,96.2017Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1797.5176,95.4492l2.6448.801Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M80.8346,97.251q1.3275-.3888,2.6553-.7772Q82.1626,96.8627,80.8346,97.251Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1802.06,96.6724l2.1116.5958Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M76.8271,98.2425l2.1108-.5394Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1806.051,97.7136l2.1222.5577Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M72.83,99.252l2.1223-.4829Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M316.0026,48.9831l1.9462-.2342Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M68.83,100.2166l2.1281-.4188Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M64.83,101.2264l2.122-.4617Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1818.0286,100.832q1.0689.251,2.1378.5019Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1824.5272,102.43l2.6355.7448Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1829.05,103.71l2.1174.5917Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M322.0027,47.9822l1.9524-.2079Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1842.5873,107.351l2.4236.7063Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1497.0375,37.7774l2.1355.377Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1846.4749,108.53l2.6877.683Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M31.8376,110.3055q1.3244-.4244,2.6491-.8484Q33.1624,109.8816,31.8376,110.3055Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1490.0225,36.8593l2.1446.323Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M24.8256,112.2547l2.1123-.5547Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1858.0411,111.7593l2.117.6572Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M20.8334,113.34l2.1257-.5438Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M1482.0283,35.82l1.9888.2739Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M13.8467,115.4043q1.353-.3957,2.7065-.7911Q15.2,115.0091,13.8467,115.4043Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M401.8349,36.18l2.1457-.28Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M409.8323,35.1591l2.1355-.3228Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M503.0031,23.98l1.9638-.15Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="M302.9861,51.0851q1.2933-.2107,2.5868-.421Q304.28,50.8752,302.9861,51.0851Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>
```

Screenshot of issue: https://i.imgur.com/t2kjfkx.png

Comment: I think you can keep only the first path and delete everything else. Apparently this is solving your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @enxaneta mentioned in the OP comments, removing all but first path resolves the issue. Illustrator showed 5 or 6 extra paths creating that flat bit at the top.

New SVG

```
<svg id="a1c72157-41bb-43e5-9ecb-ca4cc4c406e1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920.1141 217.1052">
    <path d="M1921,131c0,27.1667-.1,54.3341.1133,81.4991.03,3.856-.7636,4.6068-4.6133,4.6061Q959,216.9407,1,217V120l2.4731-1.5564,10.3736-3.0393,2.7067-.7908,4.28-1.2731,2.1257-.5438,1.8665-.5419,2.1123-.5547,4.9-1.3945,2.6494-.8481,1.4889-.3091,5.5751-1.604L64.83,101.2264l2.122-.4617,1.8787-.5481,2.1281-.4188L72.83,99.252l2.1223-.4829,1.8746-.5266,2.1108-.5394,1.8967-.4521,2.6556-.7768,1.4791-.2725,2.5079-.7708,1.5017-.2979,2.5077-.6843,1.49-.2912,1.9714-.4087,1.8842-.54,2.1213-.4361,1.8758-.54,2.1273-.4474,1.8739-.4788,2.1258-.5228,1.8753-.4771,2.1244-.5225,1.8737-.5236,2.1313-.4511,1.876-.4629,3.0942-.659,1.8964-.5354,2.1149-.4281,1.89-.4443,2.1228-.4955,2.878-.6155,2.65-.7016,1.4861-.2747,2.5241-.7371L165.8317,77.19l2.1222-.4145,1.8861-.4815,3.69-.7365,2.46-.4915,1.9514-.3447,1.8934-.5193,3.0922-.528,1.9059-.4743,2.1267-.4,2.87-.6079,2.1128-.4739,2.8945-.531,2.6922-.6279,2.4486-.4166,2.5678-.5711,2.4436-.4957,1.9537-.3578,1.8927-.4369,3.1106-.5344,1.89-.4337,3.1109-.5627,1.894-.3764,3.1121-.5974,2.8751-.5572,2.126-.4452,1.89-.3889,3.1209-.5484,2.8677-.6347,3.0977-.5143,1.9076-.4333,3.7149-.6035,2.423-.4849,1.9871-.35,8.8757-1.573,2.7221-.6L262.99,58.06l2.5445-.51,2.4579-.501,1.9756-.2091,8.8629-1.6852,2.1363-.322,2.8743-.45,3.1054-.6309,2.8944-.3938,3.1071-.5948,3.891-.6242,2.7084-.5141,3.4381-.5389,2.5871-.42,3.4162-.5987,3.5249-.5528,3.4883-.53,1.9462-.2342,4.0539-.7667,1.9524-.2079,8.8843-1.4447,3.1185-.5313,3.8756-.5682,3.1072-.51,2.8964-.4658,4.0957-.5591,2.9016-.48,3.1217-.4223,2.8829-.4821,4.1091-.5466,2.8908-.4556,4.1007-.5792,4.033-.5608,3.57-.5841,3.43-.4167,3.5809-.5522,2.4158-.4172,3.9762-.4411,4.0415-.6766,2.9707-.2829,3.877-.6174,2.1457-.28,5.8517-.741,2.1355-.3228,4.8683-.5834,3.13-.4124,5.0085-.682,3.948-.4925,1.9127-.45,5.1143-.4447,2.885-.5281,4.1325-.4008,4.867-.6614,4.1189-.3992,3.8864-.4745,4.1114-.532,6.0285-.6509,3.5676-.5209,5.4329-.4816,3.5628-.5363,5.4441-.5024,2.9554-.3435,6.0527-.7067,2.962-.24,7.0461-.8134,1.9638-.15,6.0293-.806,3.9568-.2447,5.0195-.5974,2.9985-.3226,6.8648-.6253,4.1166-.455,5.8863-.5381,5.105-.4927,5.0253-.553,5.9661-.4784,3.9041-.4954,7.0973-.499,4.9014-.54,5.1068-.43,7.0282-.5822,4.9747-.407,8.0328-.6418,3.9763-.32,8.0208-.6649,5.9607-.4065,5.0435-.6193,6.9731-.3176,5.8814-.6318,3.1422-.27,10.8592-.6839,4.1379-.3273,10.8631-.6261,5.1311-.3975L677.9678,9.2l5.995-.3724,6.8781-.5822,11.1159-.4428,6.8833-.5678L721.9414,6.74l5.9028-.4173L740.9491,5.77l10.0146-.5448,13.9807-.4728,12.0248-.5668,10.9789-.42,20.0228-.591,11.985-.3766,27.0179-.6432,24.9442-.508,3.93-.0917,54.161-.5281L941,.9988l15,0,8.989.0342,45.155.5634,1.931.0408,33.9544.5044L1062.058,2.7l19.9728.4507,13.0285.545,15.9711.4533,11.0323.5338,12.9739.4988,11.0194.5315,12.0972.5868,8.8942.4466,9.1069.5616,7.903.3926,10.097.6166,6.8918.43,10.108.5776,5.89.43,10.1109.5545,4.893.4256,9.109.5273,5.8839.51,5.9857.3636,7.0265.5734,5.9839.483,8.0034.582,5.0044.4655,6.01.4737,5.9773.4511,5.0351.5,6.9578.4629,5.0426.5329,6.9586.4717,5.0363.55,5.9707.49,5.03.503,6.0971.54,4.8991.4724,6.0944.6581,4.8886.4157,5.1138.5707,4.8816.449,5.12.5387,3.8792.4713,5.1246.3945,3.8831.5653,3.9607.2769,6.0287.7739,2.9711.2259,4.4925.46,4.52.6022,4.48.3973,4.5316.6609,4.4563.3756,4.6744.6773,4.8925.5151,4.1118.5033,3.8894.4912,5.1093.5478,3.8709.5417,5.121.5677,3.8655.5024,4.1384.4652,1.8947.3741,5.1087.4463,2.8826.5914,2.9759.3644,5.0121.6908,3.1313.4155,4.8637.6021,1.9888.2739,6.0054.7657,2.1446.323,4.87.5951,2.1355.3769,2.8875.5334,5.1015.5942,1.9042.388,5.0955.5793,1.9107.3915,3.9617.54,2.447.3436,4.5646.7162,3.9906.5523,3.1259.5169,3.8714.4918,3.1228.5808,2.88.4023,3.1278.5357,1.8937.3768,4.109.4932,1.9044.4494,4.0894.5071,2.8916.5692,2.9753.4288,2.4629.3572,3.5356.6284,3.4231.5109,2.7111.4705,3.8875.6293,3.1175.5394,1.9038.3761,4.0931.6423,1.8975.3977,4.1011.614,1.8992.3789,4.0981.6611,1.8941.3637,4.1039.6534,2.8653.503,2.1464.4033,12.8843,2.4469,3.1121.43,2.8747.629,1.9763.3032,2.47.4269,3.5548.6983,2.4189.396,2.7045.5311,3.8673.6882,2.1345.4738,2.8834.4293,3.1007.7239,1.8916.3114,3.1142.6517,1.881.3819,3.129.52,1.87.48,2.1345.3549,2.8678.6289,1.9854.3516,2.4375.4511,2.5606.5258,2.4435.4432,2.5666.61,2.4447.3773,2.6879.7124,2.8756.5216,2.13.5083,1.8786.4592,3.1187.5085,1.8765.5082,1.9706.319,2.42.551,2.59.4923,2.4171.5258,2.72.5864,1.9014.418,2.1139.5315,2.868.562,2.1265.5442,6.8612,1.5131,2.1382.3841,1.8782.5317,1.9551.3069,6.45,1.5309,2.5846.6483,1.4939.2305,2.6337.7292,2.8693.6385,2.13.5216,1.88.4207,2.1274.4513,1.8864.4926,7.1018,1.61,1.876.4878,2.1336.4843,1.8683.4969,2.1326.522,1.87.4615,2.132.5045,1.8686.4976,2.13.4328,1.8707.5646,2.1263.467,1.8764.52,1.98.4144,1.4721.3225,2.53.6724,1.4895.3051,2.6448.8009,1.898.4222,2.1116.5957,1.879.4455,2.1222.5576,1.8649.5106,6.125,1.5045,1.8655.5457,2.1378.5019,4.3608,1.0958,2.6355.7448,1.8873.5357,2.1174.5916,11.42,3.0492,2.4236.7063,1.464.4724,2.6877.683,1.8689.6094,5.137,1.4411,1.8726.4961,2.117.6571,4.8775,1.3605,8.1314,2.3888,1.8771.5833,5.1234,1.4824,4.3132,1.2614,5.69,1.672,1.8585.6707,8.1394,2.4273,13.37,4.1343,5.6251,1.9Z" transform="translate(-1)" fill="#fff" />
</svg>
```